# Using AJAX return JS variable to JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a simple JS function which retrieves some data from the URL in browser. Call to that JS function is made in a JSP. The JS function is called from within a  tag in JSP.

JS Function:

```
function parseURL(){
  var info = "some value",  // This is retrieved from the browser URL which is my.JSP

  $.ajax({

     method: post,
     url: my.jsp   // This is the same URL (browser URL) from which I am getting information, so I just send back to it
      data: { information: info} )}

      .done({
              alert("Success"); 
         })
  });
}
```

When I try to retrieve the value in a scriplet in JSP, it is returning null. What am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: I would also like to mention that in `.done` if I do `alert(data)`, I get the whole HTML page with the correct `information` value. Why is the whole HTML page getting returned in `post` instead of just the `data`?

Comment: it's normal to get back the whole HTML code of your page , to have only the data you want you should send the post to another page (in the url ) and in it you can set the data you want to get back with no HTML code just the data you want

Comment: @PacMan So you suggest have url to say `another.jsp` and then have a scriptlet there to retrieve `data` from json key values using request.getParameter ?

Comment: @PacMan I just tried that by changing url to another jsp but the value is still null. For my application purpose, I need to display data back on the same original URL. I cannot go to another jsp for display purpose. Is there a reason as to why I cant make the page return json data back to the same original URL ?

Answer (score 0):

i can suggest you to follow these steps and find an approach to your case !!

first in your function

```
    function parseURL(){
  var info = "some value",  // This is retrieved from the browser URL which is my.JSP

  $.ajax({
     method: post,
     url: anotherPage.jsp   // This is the same URL (browser URL) from which I am getting information, so I just send back to it
      data: { information: info} )}
      .done({
              $("div or section where you want to inject the result").html(data);
         })
  });
}
```

and in the anotherPage.jsp try to have something like this :

//jsp header and stuff and the data you want to get back such as scriplet or expression just the data that would be injected by the function ahead
if you could post the my.jsp and the anotherPage.jsp that could be helpful

Comment: It doesn't work. How do you suggest to send data back to my.jsp? It is an application using OAuth, if I go to another JSP then I loose the content from my.jsp.